# How to remove text from before a word?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Looking for a way to remove `[11:55:43] [Server thread/INFO]:` from the line below:

```
[11:55:43] [Server thread/INFO]: Justin has just earned the achievement [Time to Mine!]
```

Have attempted to do this through using sed but had no luck, as the name Justin can change to another users name depending on who gains an achievement.

Is there a way I can remove `[11:55:43] [Server thread/INFO]:` before the users name without having to specify it? Ie. sed from has, but keep the word in front and remove anything ahead of that?

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
sed 's/\[.*\] \[.*\]: //' file
Justin has just earned the achievement [Time to Mine!]
```

Comment: That doesn't work if there are more occurences of `]:` in the input file.
For example, doesn't work with `[11:55:43] [Server thread/INFO]: Justin has just earned ]: the achievement [Time to Mine!]`

Answer (score 1):

A `sed` command to achieve that is:

```
sed 's/^.*: //'
```

e.g.

```
echo '[11:55:43] [Server thread/INFO]: Justin has just earned the achievement [Time to Mine!]' |\
    sed 's/^.*: //'
Justin has just earned the achievement [Time to Mine!]
```

Comment: Assumes there are no colons in the text beyond the desired one. Might be better to match two `[...]` blocks instead.

Comment: yes, fully agree... but that answer was provided shortly after mine, so I won't plagiarise.

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/^\[[^]]*\][^[]*\[[^]]*\]: //'
```

That will remove the start of each line if it matches `[`(something)`]`(something)`[`(something)`]:`

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
sed 's/.*: \([^ ]* has .*\)/\1/' file
```

Comment: The name was failing because he try to add the name in the pattern but the request don't ask to include this nor *has.* like i supect he put in his failing sed.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/^\( *\[[^]]*]\)\{2\}: //' YourFile
```

- Allow also any space between `[...]`
- assuming there is no `]:` in 2 first `[...]` content like in your sample
- printing lines no matching the structure unchanged

posix compliant (so `--posix` with GNU sed)

Answer (score 0):

A `gawk`.

Source file:

```
$ cat infile
[11:55:43] [Server thread/INFO]: Justin has just earned the achievement [Time to Mine!]
[11:58:43] [Server thread/INFO]: Martin has just earned the achievement [Time to Mine!]
```

Code:

```
$ gawk -F']: '  'BEGIN{OFS=""}{$1=""}1'  infile
Justin has just earned the achievement [Time to Mine!]
Martin has just earned the achievement [Time to Mine!]
```

Comment: what about `[11:55:43] [Server thread/INFO]: Justin has:  just 0$. Earned: 1$  [Time to Mine!] `

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intension.

Comment: Still fails if `]: ` appears in the string somewhere else. You should probably just drop `$1`.

Comment: Coming through this comment very late ...  you were very right @EtanReisner